# AngularJS Edmunds REST API Call - loading dropdowns doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, rest

I am trying to query Edmunds.com REST API to pull down cars based on make and model.

In my sample, I simply wanted to ping their API to get all makes and show them in a dropdown. Once you select a make, I want to get a list of all models for that make and load Models dropdown with it.

I am not able to get it to work. I am thinking something is wrong with my carController. The error I see in Chrome debugger is "Argument 'carController' is not a function, got undefined". I do have carController but for reason it doesn't like it.
Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here's the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/h0zAInSk1wIo0PRQNxGL?p=preview

```
//carController.js
    (function() {
  var app = angular.module('AngularSamples', []);

    var carController = function($scope, $http) {
      // get all the makes
        $http.get('https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/makes?state=new&view=basic&fmt=json&api_key=mexvxqeke9qmhhawsfy8j9qd')
        .then(function (response)
              {
                $scope.makes = response.data;
                }, function (error) {
                $scope.error1 = JSON.stringify(error);
                });

        // for each make - get all the models.
        $scope.getmodels = function(make) {
            $http.get('https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/"+make+"/models?state=new&view=basic&fmt=json&api_key=mexvxqeke9qmhhawsfy8j9qd')
        .then(function (response)
              {
                $scope.models = response.data;
                }, function (error) {
                $scope.error2 = JSON.stringify(error);
                });
        };

        app.controller('carController', ['$scope', '$http', carController]);
    };
})();
```

Here's the API link that I try to hit and get back the JSON:
https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/makes?state=new&year=2014&view=basic&fmt=json&api_key=mexvxqeke9qmhhawsfy8j9qd

Comment: API doesn't seem to be CORS enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a simple error and you'll kick yourself when you see what's wrong. Swap these two lines:

```
    app.controller('carController', ['$scope', '$http', carController]);
};
```

to read:

```
};

app.controller('carController', ['$scope', '$http', carController]);
```

You are defining carController as a var near the top of your example above. But then you're trying to use it from INSIDE itself. You just need to move this line of code to outside the controller.

By the way, your Plnkr doesn't work because of an additional mistake but I'm assuming this was just a cut/paste issue - you're asking for js/carController.js but in Plunkr that file is at the top level.

You had one or two other small issues that I fixed up in this Plnkr. The Makes selector is now working. Models is not but it's because the API is returning an empty array for the query you're using - I don't know this API so you'll need to Inspect the network request and fix anything that's wrong with it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BGY76tIXhprPWgt5aphx?p=preview

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I also see an issue with my second API request so I should be able to resolve it quickly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If anyone needs to look at the final version with both the dropdowns working here it is : http://plnkr.co/edit/zKRA5kq6tXWTaLe5tETB?p=preview